# Binding background property inside template of LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, datatemplate, longlistselector

I have Class MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
{

    public string MyColor { get; set; }

    public class TeamOfCreators : ObservableCollection<Creator>
    {
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    }
    public ObservableCollection<TeamOfCreators> TeamsOfCreators { get; set; }

}
```

And Xaml:

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding MyClass.TeamsOfCreators}" Height="530">
                    <toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Background="{Binding MyColor, Converter={StaticResource NativeColorConverter}}" />      
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

How should I bind Background, to get there MyColor? How should look the binding in Background in xaml?

Comment: How have you set the xaml DataContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DataTemplate, the DataContext is an object, e.g. for a `TeamCreator`. `TeamCreator` does not have a property called `MyColor` - does each `TeamCreator` have it own color, or is there just one color for all objects?

If each `TeamCreator` has its own color, move the `MyColor` property to the `TeamCreator` class.

If you want to control the background property for all `TeamCreator` objects from `MyClass`, you'll have to access the DataContext outside of the DataTemplate.

For example, if you've set your DataContext on, say, your Window,

```
<Window x:Name="MyWindow">

<toolkit:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding TeamsOfCreators}">
    <toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="{Binding DataContext.MyColor, 
                                         ElementName=MyWindow, 
                                         Converter={StaticResource NativeColorConverter}}"/>      
                <!-- ... -->
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListSelector>
```